# My heroku app works on my pc but on others pc or smartphone it doesnt let the backend working

Tags: reactjs, github, heroku, mern

My Heroku app works on my pc but on others pc or smartphone it doesn't let the backend working.
what should I do its a weird error?

here is the link of my [repo](https://book-box-by-bs.herokuapp.com/) /  here is the link of the Heroku app [Google  books search mern](https://github.com/masterkaizer/gb852963.git)

Comment: What is the error, and what does it say in the browser console of the other PC?

Comment: it says nothing special just the backend will not connect to frontend

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your repo, I would double check your database and API calls. In your client, you are fetching data from a localhost URL. If you are running React client side, the API call will try to fetch information locally on your device instead of from the Heroku server.

It's working on your desktop because you most likely have a MongoDB and node instance running locally.

If that's the case, I would recommend using environment variables for development and production to automatically configure which API base url is being used.

Comment: so what should i put it can you show me what to put?